# Compare Entity Framework Schema to Database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I cannot find an answer for this. But, how do I get the database schema from EF (using 5 atm)?

I want to compare the EF schema to a `.mdf` file's schema to see wether they will be compatible.

For the `.mdf` file, I read it into a dataset, then use

```
string currentDsSchema = dsMan.DataSet.GetXmlSchema();
```

but, have no idea how to read it from EF.

Answer (score 0):

EF model files are not compatible with xml schemas; they have their own format. Maybe you should create the database from EF schema and compare generated db with the existing db.